# Sign sha256 hash with RSA using pkcs#11 api?

Tags: rsa, pkcs#11

I'm currently using pyPkcs11 to sign files.

The following call works for signing common files with RSA and sha256,

```
session.sign(privKey, toSign, Mechanism(CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS, None)
```

But some of my files are already hashed (sha256), and the signature needs to give the same output that would be given by this openSSL command:

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -in <inFilePath> -inkey <keyPath> -out <outFilePath>
```

I have tried the following call, which does not generate a hash of the file before signature,

```
session.sign(privKey, toSign, Mechanism(CKM_RSA_PKCS, None)
```

But the result is not the one i expected, and according to the first answer of this post [CKM_RSA_PKCS vs CKM_RSA_X_509 mechanisms in PKCS#11](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9593/ckm-rsa-pkcs-vs-ckm-rsa-x-509-mechanisms-in-pkcs11),

> CKM_RSA_PKCS on the other hand also performs the padding as defined in the PKCS#1 standards. This padding is defined within EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5, steps 3, 4 and 5. This means that this mechanism should only accept messages that are 11 bytes shorter than the size of the modulus. To create a valid RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signature, you need to perform steps 1 and 2 of EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5 yourself.

After some research it appears that my file contains the first step of the signature described by the [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-9.2), so the missing part is the second one, where the ASN.1 value is generated.

**Can I force this operation with pkcs11 and how ?**

The [PKCS#11 documentation](https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/STANDARD/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf) doesn't seem to contain any information about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see two ways to do this; the appropriate one depends on the token (not all tokens/wrappers do all machanisms).

- As explained in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47106123/903600), you could decorate the 32-octet SHA-256 that you start from into a full padded message representative. Basically, as explained in [PKCS#1 for RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A90%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C721%2Cnull%5D) with reference to [EMSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A114%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C513%2Cnull%5D), if the RSA key is *k* octets (with I assume _k_≥51+11=62 octets, that is a public modulus at least 8⋅62-7=489 bits, which is a must for security), you

  1. Append on the left the 19-octet string

```
30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20
```

yielding a 51-octet string, which really is the [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) encoding for the hash type and value per

```
DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithm,
digest OCTET STRING
}
```

2. Further append on the left the string of *k*-51 octets (of which *k*-51-3 are `FF`)

```
00 01 FF FF FF FF..FF FF FF FF 00
```

yielding a *k*-octet string
3. Sign with mechanism **CKM_RSA_X_509** (length *k* octets).

- Or, alternatively: perform as in [1.]; skip [2.]; and in [3.] use mechanism **CKM_RSA_PKCS** (length 51 octets).

Disclaimer: I did not check, and have not used a PKCS#11 device lately.

Note: While there is no known attack against proper implementations of it, use of PKCS#1 v1.5 signature padding is increasingly frowned at; e.g. [French authorities recommend](https://www.ssi.gouv.fr/uploads/2014/11/RGS_v-2-0_B1.pdf#page=22)

> RecomSignAsym-1.    Il est recommandé d’employer des mécanismes de signature asymétrique disposant d’une preuve de sécurité.

Or, in English:

> It is recommended to use asymmetric signature mechanisms featuring a security proof

They mention RSA-SSA-PSS (*sic*). As a bonus, the PKCS#11 implementation of that is mechanism **CKM_RSA_PKCS_PSS** which accepts a hash, rather than the data to sign, making what's asked trivial.

Comment: Thank you, i will do it as soon as i can.
For the Note, as the files and the signature mechanism are not an intern choice but are decided my the client, i do not have control about them

Comment: I don't understand. If CKM_RSA_PKCS_PSS accepts an hash as input, what is the purpose of hashAlg member of the CK_RSA_PKCS_PSS_PARAMS struct ? "hashAlg : hash algorithm used in the PSS encoding : if the signature mechanism does not include message hashing, then this value must be the mechanism used by the application to generate message hash" (source Pkcs11 documentation)

Comment: ok i have my answer : CKM_<hash>_RSA_PKCS_PSS is a C_Digest with <hash> followed by CKM_RSA_PKCS_PSS. CKM_RSA_PKCS_PSS use hashAlg (two times), mgf and saltLen for the padding. Moreover, it seems that CKM_<hash>_RSA_PKCS_PSS use <hash> not only for the C_digest but also as default hashAlg for the padding.

Comment: @kingsjester: [fixing my previous, deleted comment] hashAlg of CK_RSA_PKCS_PSS_PARAMS then is used to determine which hash is used to produce the internal quantity H in [EMSA-PSS](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A102%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C118%2C721%2Cnull%5D). That should match the hash that's _externally_ used to produce the message hash mHash. The hash used in MGF1 is stated by the value CK_RSA_PKCS_MGF_TYPE (and it's a good idea that it matches).

Comment: @fgrieu-onstrike yes good idea that MGF matches but it is not required to have a successful Sign/verify (i tested). On the other hand, if hashAlg != <mechanism used by the application to generate message hash>, you will have CKR_MECHANISM_PARAM_INVALID after C_SignInit (i tested also).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, there is no PKCS#11 function, which can do what you want.

The only solution that I am aware of would be, to apply the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding manually to your hash and then sign the block using the **CKM_RSA_X_509** (raw or textbook RSA) mechanism.

Comment: Thank you, i was afraid this would be the only solution

Answer (score 0):

Rather than issuing the command,

```
openssl pkeyutl -sign -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -in <inFilePath> -inkey <keyPath> -out <outFilePath>
```

try

```
 openssl dgst --sha256 -sign <keyPath> -sha256 -out <signature file> <inFilePath>
```

This produces 256 bytes signature that would probably be identical to
one generated by Pkcs11 C_Sign